# Date Formatter not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

I want to change my date format from "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss" to "EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a", but the code I am using not working for example if my input is 11/30/2016T01:04:30 I am getting the month changed as December, can any one help where is the mistake?

```
NSString * date = @"11/30/2016T01:04:30";
date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dayName= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"the converted Day  %@",dayName);
```

Comment: what you want out put just tell me

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya want to convert --- MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss-- format to --EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a --

Comment: @Arun You are facing this issue because of capital `YYYY` in first date Formate it should be small `yyyy` Also there is no need to use two dateFormatter you can work with single once and instead of replacing `T` with space simply change your dateFormate to `MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @NiravD tanks it working now

Comment: @Arun Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need of this

```
// date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
```

use like

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSString * date = @"11/30/2016T01:04:30";

[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: date];

[df setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dayName= [df stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"the converted Day  %@",dayName);
```

**Output:**

```
the converted Day  Wed 30 Nov 2016 01:04 AM
```

Comment: and also check your timezone also, if you need